# .pro.shared not loaded by Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt-creator, qmake

I want to select the dirs for the outputs (moc, rcc, .o), the path for the final .exe and to keep the makefiles out of the source directory.
So I created a .pro.shared to share the build directories between users.
My idea was not to version the .pro.user but a small .pro.shared instead.
When I set everything up it worked, but now on a another branch it doesn't.
I loose the definition of the build dir inside Qt Creator.

Here is what I did:

#### The .pro.shared

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE QtCreatorProject>
<qtcreator>
  <data>
    <variable>ProjectExplorer.Project.Target.0</variable>
    <valuemap type="QVariantMap">
      <valuemap type="QVariantMap" key="ProjectExplorer.Target.BuildConfiguration.0">
        <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory">../qtcreatorbuilds/debug</value>
      </valuemap>
      <valuemap type="QVariantMap" key="ProjectExplorer.Target.BuildConfiguration.1">
        <value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory">../qtcreatorbuilds/release</value>
      </valuemap>
    </valuemap>
  </data>
</qtcreator>
```

#### The .pro

```
build_root_dir = $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/../qtcreatorbuilds
release: DESTDIR = $${build_root_dir}/release
debug:   DESTDIR = $${build_root_dir}/debug

OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/qtinternal/obj
MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/qtinternal/moc
RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/qtinternal/qrc
UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/qtinternal/ui
```

It was working fine on my branch but now that I merged the changes in the trunk, It doesn't work anymore.
I mean that in the project settings panel, the build dir is not `../qtcreatorbuilds/release` for exemple but something else (the root of the project).
Almost everything is done properly only the Makefiles are not generated where I would expect them to be. But still I'd like to understand!

Note: I don't know if this is useful but I disabled the shadow build.
Otherwise the project doesn't compile (because of an issue inside moc files)...

Does anybody know how the definition of the build dir can be done for sure in configuration files of Qt Creator?

Thanks!